# How to rebuild PR github without making a new commit that checks failed due to network

Tags: javascript, git, github

How to rebuild PR that checks failed due to network issue.

I want rebuild PR without making any new commit.

[build failed screenshot is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qUYo.png)

Comment: Most CI systems have a method to re-run a build. Click the `Details` link and see if you can run it again

Comment: What build system are you using? Normally, you could trigger a new build of that PR in your build system (like Jenkins) and it should automatically inform GitHub about the updated result.

Comment: This is a duplicate. It has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408592/how-to-relaunch-github-check-without-pushing-new-commits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to relaunch GitHub check without pushing new commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408592/how-to-relaunch-github-check-without-pushing-new-commits)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using Github Actions and the thing you want to achieve here is re-running a custom workflow.

Refer to the docs https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs